# Connectionstring Encryption in MVC2 .NET 4.0 app

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have an MVC2 .NET 4.0 app, hosted on TFS 2008 (soon to be TFS 2010) that uses connection strings in `web.config` to connect to a database on another server.  I need to encrypt these connection strings.

As I understand it, I can use `aspnet_regiis.exe` to encrypt the connectionstring portion of the `web.config` file, *but I have to do it on the deployment machine* because the encryption uses the machine name to generate the encryption key.

Now, it seems to me that this represents a problem - every time I deploy my code to the dev server won't it overwrite the web.config file, and need to be re-encrypted?  This sort of manual process seems kludgy.

1. Is my understanding about needing to re-encrypt after deployment correct?
2. If so, is there some way to automate this process? I don't want to forget this or get a new team member who doesn't know the process and have the connectionstring exposed to the world.

Answer (score 0):

web.config files aren't typically part of a deployment (though Visual Studio 2010 supports [configuration file transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) in web application deployment projects).  I wouldn't expect that you should be overwriting the web.config when you deploy (because the web.config is where you would place those things that are specific to that machine/environment.

So, encrypt it once, and then don't overwrite it, would be my advice.

Since that isn't available in your situation, it is possible to specify a key when encrypting, so that you can share the encrypted file between machines.  By default, the command to encrypt uses the DPAPI to encrypt the section (which is tied to the machine) but you can also use RSA for encryption.  More info is available on MSDN in [Specifying a Protected Configuration Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68ze1hb2.aspx).

Comment: There are many times a web.config will need to be re-deployed.  If you store application settings in the web.config and they change, if IOC configuration changes, view engine name space changes, etc..

Comment: sadly, our deployment to dev consists of drag & drop of the files to the server - so web.config actually gets overwritten every time.  I know this isn't optimal, but it's not within my power to change.