# How to store accounts access informations inside ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I need to keep access settings to different web pages inside of my asp.net application. These setting are logins and passwords for those pages. Is it safe enough to keep them in web.config in  section??

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you mean roles allowed for pages? Why would you store logins and passwords to individual pages in web.config? You can authenticate the user with Forms Authentication and then authorize the user through web.config settings.

Comment: Consider using Roles instead of multiple user/pwd setting for each page. If you using ASP.NET MVC - the concept of areas would do. In typical ASP.NET world, you can use Folders to segregate the pages.

Comment: I mean access to completly another services. Let`s say I have some house, flats offers which I need to export on dedicated services as zipped files throught the FTP. I need to keeps login and passwords settings for all of those services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you COULD keep log in information and passwords in your web.config and you can protect those sections by encrypting them. I don't know if that's the most suitable place to do so, but given your description I'll assume that it is the best solution for your case.

Here is a robust way to implement encryption: [What is the proper method for encrypting ASP.NET connetionStrings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073443/what-is-the-proper-method-for-encrypting-asp-net-connetionstrings/5073646#5073646)

```
private void ProtectSection(string sectionName,
                                   string provider)
{
    Configuration config =
        WebConfigurationManager.
            OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);

    ConfigurationSection section =
                 config.GetSection(sectionName);

    if (section != null &&
              !section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
        config.Save();
    }
}

private void UnProtectSection(string sectionName)
{
    Configuration config =
        WebConfigurationManager.
            OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);

    ConfigurationSection section =
              config.GetSection(sectionName);

    if (section != null &&
          section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
        config.Save();
    }
}
```

So to protect the settings you just call the ProtectSection method with the section you wish to protect and the protection provider of your choice (usually `DataProtectionConfigurationProvider` or `RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider`):

```
ProtectSection("appSettings", "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
```

To un-protect a section you call the UnProtectSection method with the section you want to unprotect:

```
UnProtectSection("appSettings");
```